# For loop runs once, 2/3 of the way (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, for-loop

```
function clearObjects() {
    var co = document.getElementsByClassName("clearable");
    var i;
    alert("function runs");
    for (i = 0; i < co.length; i++) {
        alert("for loop runs 1/3");
        alert("for loop runs 2/3, time to erase");
        co[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        alert("for loop runs 1, erased 1");
    };
};
clearObjects();
```

This function that I has here is suppose to change the color of all divs with the class of clearable to a background color of white, where they are "Erased." The function runs inside of my other code, but my issue is that the for loop stops running when it gets to:

```
co[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
```

I put alerts in there to see what parts of the function run, and the final alert "for loop runs 1, erased 1" does not alert, and the for loop does not run again. I have looked and could not find a problem similar to mine. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I will post all of my code if neccessary. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser's console?

Comment: This may not be an option for you, but with jQuery (which you have tagged) you can just do `$('.clearable').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');` and it'll do the entire function in one line.

Comment: [Don't use `alert()` for debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx). Open the [browser's error console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and check for errors (and use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` in the future.)

Comment: No, no errors anywhere, and all the other code works fine. Its only the loop that fails.

Comment: wait, yes i do have console errors:

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: clearableObjects is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: clearableObjects is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: clearableObjects is not defined
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: Though you don't show it here, are you changing the class? If you're removing the  `"clearable"` class, then the collection gets automatically updated and reindexed.

Comment: Pluto, that is a great suggestion and I may try it. I would just like to try to do things with javascript because I am still learning it and jquery is kinda cheating to me.

Comment: `clearableObjects` does not appear anywhere in the code you posted. I think this is not the same code you are actually running.

Comment: squint, the only time I change the class is to add the class to new divs I am creating. But, that is not in the same code group, so that may be the problem.

Comment: So this is exactly how the code that you're running looks?

Comment: It isn't cheating to use jQuery, it can be much more convenient than the native DOM methods. But whatever you use, get familiar with the JavaScript debugger. There are many ways it can help you in addition to the `console.log()` that Juhana suggested. In particular, you can use the interactive debugger to step through your code line by line and examine the variables at each step. For example, add a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of your `clearObjects()` function and run the code with the developer tools open. It will stop on that line and you can single step through the code.

Comment: this is the codepen: http://codepen.io/DITTODITTO/pen/LVQPgJ     I looked in the codepen and didnt find anything about ClearableObjects, which was the var that was replaced by co

Comment: Here is a great [introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Other browsers have similar tools.

Comment: What do you mean by the elements being *"Erased"*?

Comment: For learning purposes, I think it's useful to know how to do things with native Javascript (setting CSS properties, making ajax calls, or accessing `data-` properties) so feel free to not use jQuery because it can help you in the long run.

Comment: squint erased means to change the divs that are created as the mouse moves to white so they appear to not be there. The issue is when I click f (key code 70) and try to clear all of those. They naturally get put in the class "clearable" so when I click f to erase them all, they should all disapear.

Comment: But I mean do they get removed from the DOM, or just hidden with CSS?

Comment: They get changed to white.

Comment: The CSS property visible would be better for the "erase" function you are achieving with the white background. It will work regardless of the background. If this will ever be put into production that will matter, otherwise, no big deal.

Comment: I did `document.getElementsByClassName('clearable')` and got no results. You're setting 'class' as a CSS property to be 'clearable' which is not right.

Comment: pluto what is your solution?

Comment: Ah, @Pluto's got it. I didn't study the code in the link. They're not getting the class at all. DITTO: Please always put relevant code directly in the question, and reduce it down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by setting the visibility to hidden instead of background to white, and by setting the class of the new divs with jquery's attr() function instead of what I had. It works perfectly now, thanks for all the input!

Comment: You were asking a different question which is about the a loop, people were simply addressing the question you asked. The solution you found is for a different issue. The answer below did work as intended, however, vote it down is simply bad

Comment: ...I was asking why it failed, not specifically what was wrong with the loop. I fixed the issue with their help...what are you talking about???

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were running into is that you were attempting to set the class of each drawn object in CSS. The change to fix that is changing this:

```
var div = $('<div>').css({
    'class': 'clearable'
});
```

To this:

```
var div = $('<div>').css({
    ...
}).addClass('clearable');
```

You can also remove the element easily by using `co[i].parentNode.removeChild(co[i])` instead of changing the background color (frees up memory). I've reversed the direction of the loop in my example because you're dealing with removing elements (and that shifts the array one element backwards causing you to skip an item each time if going forwards).

See my code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNYRWE